# How to read app.config for outlook add in

Tags: .net, outlook, add-in

I would like to know following 2 things.

I am using outlook 2007 Add in.

1. How to read App setting for deployed outlook plugin.

I have used following things for this to read configuration file.

```
ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase.ToLower().Replace("file:///", ""));
```

Please let me know if you have better way for this.

2.For calling WCF client i need to load all wcf configuration defined in App.config

```
       EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(endPoint.Address);
                        serviceWS = new serviceWS(new BasicHttpBinding(), endpointAddress);
```

I would like to load all app.config setting for WCF.

3.Also I would like to know if it is possible to change dll.config deployed on machine and reflect those changes in plugin(make sure plugin read dll.config)

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

To answer part one. I put my configurations in the App.config of my Addin

You will need to override ConfigurationSection and you may need to look at ConfigurationElementCollection & ConfigurationElement all in the System.Configuration namespace

The App.config is deployed with the addin so you shouldn't have to do anything fancier than this

```
var section = (MyAwesomeConfigSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("AwesomeConfigSection");
```

I don't really understand the rest of your question